# How to get cfspreadsheet to render html

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfspreadsheet

I'm trying to create an excel file with cfspreadsheet. In one of the columns I have html code, but for some reason, in the excel file the html doesn't get rendered it's just plain text. eg. `<b>blabla</b>` instead of being bolded.

Do you know any solutions to this?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that `cfspreadsheet` is based on POI which [does not support html content](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Display-parsed-HTML-content-td4298794.html).

As [user1450455 mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166522/how-to-get-cfspreadsheet-to-render-html#13912431), you can format *whole* cells using any of the built in formatting functions such as SpreadsheetFormatCell.

```
  sheet = spreadSheetNew();
  spreadSheetFormatCell( sheet, {bold=true} , 1, 1 );
  spreadSheetSetCellValue( sheet, "blablah", 1, 1 );
```

If you are looking to create [cells with multiple formats](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Can-POI-Excel-change-cell-font-color-partially-td2856775.html) (ie bold some characters but not others) that is only possible using the underlying POI library by creating a [RichTextString](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html). So it requires much lower level code.

```
<cfscript>
    sheet     = spreadSheetNew();
    workbook  = sheet.getWorkBook();
    helper    = workbook.getCreationHelper();
    richText  = helper.createRichTextString("ColdFusion");

    // make first few characters bold ie "Cold"
    firstFont = workbook.createFont();
    firstFont.setBoldweight( firstFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD );
    richText.applyFont( 0, 4, firstFont );

    // make next characters red ie "Fusion"
    secondFont = workbook.createFont();
    secondFont.setColor( secondFont.COLOR_RED );
    richText.applyFont( 4, 10, secondFont );

    // create cell via CF and apply formats
    // note, in POI indexes are base 0
    spreadSheetSetCellValue( sheet, "", 2, 1);
    cellA2 = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(1).getCell(0);
    cellA2.setCellValue( richText );
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I was just going to add the link, but you beat me to it!

Comment: Heh sorry, just realised this was a recent answer - I normally wait at least 5 minutes before editing, to avoid that.

Comment: No worries. I tweak pretty frequently anyway, so chances are our edits still would have clashed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spreadsheet formatting functions like `SpreadsheetFormatRow` or `SpreadsheetFormatrows` or `SpreadsheetFormatColumns`.